# Can .cvsignore exclude patterns found in recursive subdirectories?

Tags: cvs

Can I create a single .cvsignore file to exclude specific patterns for the current directory and recursively for all subdirectories? Basically I want to say at the top of my cvs module to exclude all *.swp or *.bak files instead of having to create a new .cvsignore for each subdirectory.

I suppose this behavior would be similar to that of mercurial's .hgignore file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[CVS docs](http://docs.freebsd.org/info/cvs/cvs.info.cvsignore.html) list several solutions. In your case the following applies the best if you can access the $CVSROOT on the server:

> - The per-repository list in
>     `$CVSROOT/CVSROOT/cvsignore` is
>      appended to the list, if that file exists.

If you cannot access the $CVSROOT, then you can use other options listed there, such as:

> - The per-user list in `.cvsignore`
>     in your home directory is
>      appended to the list, if it exists.

or

> - Any entries in the environment variable `$CVSIGNORE` is
>     appended to the list.

Comment: Thanks! I read the docs and ended up creating a .cvsignore file in my home directory since I don't have access to modify the CVSROOT on the server.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the answer to include more appropriate options.